# Accessing servlet attributes using Expression Language

Tags: jsp, servlets

Two things I'm confused about.....

In the servlet class I have:

```
    String name = "James Bond";
    Session.setAttribute("name", name);
```

Why is the attribute name and attribute value the same in all the books I've read. I know one is a string literal and one is an object but must it be the same?

Second thing I'm confused about... let's say I change the servlet code to

```
    String name = "James Bond";
    Session.setAttribute("hisname", name);
```

When I try to access it using JSP:

```
    ${sessionScope.name}
```

it works fine. So what is the point of the first argument in Session.setAttribute() ?

Comment: name and value does not need to be the same.

Comment: *Why is the attribute name and attribute value the same in all the books I've read* basically, for code readability and maintenance purposes. Imagine you save `Dog` data in an object called `login` through all the application, or vice versa, and you have to do the maintenance of this application. If you work in one or two pages, it is not so painful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you store data on a scope with setAttribute() method, the first argument is the name you are going to use later in the .jsp. It can be whatever you want it to. The second argument is the object to be stored and it will be accesed using the name you used at the first one.

```
String name = "James Bond";
request.setAttribute("007",name);
```

Then in the .jsp you can acces using

```
${requestScope.007}
```

The EL expression will search the 007 object in all scopes in this order:

1. pageScope
2. requestScope
3. sessionScope
4. applicationScope

You are storing the data in Session scope, so while your session is alive, you will have the data available. So when you do:

```
String name = "James Bond";
Session.setAttribute("name", name);
```

And then store another attribute in the same scope (in the same session)

```
String name = "James Bond";
Session.setAttribute("hisname", name);
```

You wont get any errors by accessing the fist ${sessionScope.name} becouse you still have it available. Try using other scopes.

Answer (score 2):

name and value does not need to be the same.

when you do  `${sessionScope.name}` and you still got "James Bond". This must be because you still have the "name" attribute you defined available in session scope.

Change the name to something else the second time as follows:

```
String name = "James Bond";
Session.setAttribute("name", name);
String name = "The Bond";////////////////make this change. 
Session.setAttribute("hisname", name);
```

So when you do  `${sessionScope.name}` this time, you'll get "James Bond" and not "The Bond".

And if you do `${sessionScope.hisname}`, you'll get "The Bond"

Answer (score 1):

My guess, you still access the old "name" from the session, try to invalidate the session and "name" attribute will be removed !